# linq contains (int) item in array

Tags: c#, linq, contains

I'm trying to write some linq which searches for items where the value in the stored item matches any of the values in a list - I can do this easily if it's a list of strings & searching for a string, but when it's a list of enums (ints) I can't figure it out.

```
List<MyEnum> categories = new List<MyEnum>();

categories.Add(MyEnum.Fred);
categories.Add(MyEnum.Bill);
categories.Add(MyEnum.Jim);

// MyTable.Category is of type MyEnum
return (from o in Table<MyTable>()
        where categories.Any(val => o.Category.Contains(val))
        select o).Count();
```

Edited with further info -

The code is:

```
public int LocalOffersCount(double distance, List<LocalCategory> categories)
{
    try
    {
        return (from o in Table<LocalOffer>() where categories.Any(val => o.Category.Contains(val)) select o).Count();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("DatabaseService->LocalOffersCount: " + ex.Message);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

MyTable contains various items, the "Category" item is a LocalCategory enum starting at 1 going to 10.

The compile error I'm getting is -

The type arguments for method `System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(this System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, TSource)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly (CS0411)

Comment: What specific error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Why won't it compile? What is the error?

Comment: "when it's a list of enums (ints)" --> mistake #1. Enums != ints. But it would help the masses if you actually posted the error instead of only stating that it will not compile. You'll likely get an answer quicker, and you'll provide a service for those with the same problem when they search for it (we're not here to help *you* alone).

Comment: What is the type of `MyTable.Category`?

Comment: It compiles fine for me... it depends on what `MyTable` is, and `Table<MyTable>()`, and `o.Category`.. in short, not enough information to answer your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that `LocalOffer.Category` is a single `Category` (based on the name). Try this instead:

```
return 
    (from o in Table<LocalOffer>() 
     where categories.Contains(o.CategoryId) 
     select o)
    .Count();
```

However, if `LocalOffer.Category` is an `IEnumerable<Category>`, this is probably what you need:

```
return 
    (from o in Table<LocalOffer>() 
     where o.Any(c => categories.Contains(c.CategoryId))
     select o)
    .Count();
```